# Validates arguments passed to ansible-playbook with a defined argument specification

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-facts

We want to run the following playbook with the `yml` file - `ansible-playbook install_os.yml`

The `playbook install_os.yml` is working well , but now we want to add the validation of the arguments `<machine name>,<machine IP>`.

As the following:

```
ansible-playbook install_os.yml --limit RHEL01,73.22.3.44
```

From my point both arguments should be identify as strings (without verify of valid IP) and between `<machine name>` to `<machine IP>`, we should set the `,` separator

So, is it possible to validate the strings? And exit if one of them or both them are not defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the limit specified in arguments to `ansible-playbook` with the help of the special variable [`ansible_limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

From there on, you can [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) the `--limit` values based on your business needs.

For example:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - assert: 
        that: 
          ## We have exactly one comma, separating two hosts
          - ansible_limit | split(',') | length == 2
          ## We have a string before the comma
          - (ansible_limit | split(',')).0 is string
          ## We have a non-empty string before the comma
          - (ansible_limit | split(',')).0 | length > 0
          ## We have a string after the comma
          - (ansible_limit | split(',')).1 is string
          ## We have a non-empty string after the comma
          - (ansible_limit | split(',')).1 | length > 0
          ## 'all', which has a wildcard meaning, 
          ## is not one of the two hosts separated by the comma
          - "'all' not in ansible_limit | split(',')"
          ## We do not have any character having a special meaning in the limit
          ## see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns
          - "'@' not in ansible_limit"
          - "':' not in ansible_limit"
          - "'!' not in ansible_limit"
          - "'&' not in ansible_limit"
          - "'*' not in ansible_limit"
      run_once: true
```

This would probably limit it to the use case you want.
This said, mind that [`--limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags) is an existing flag with its own behaviour, so, based on what you are aiming for, you could also be better with [an extra parameter passed in command line](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).

Comment: what in case "--limit" not appears in args , can we also alert about this

Comment: Well, you can add a condition in the assertion, of course, but `ansible_limit | split(',') | length == 2` will already raise you that there is only one item to the result of splitting an empty string with a comma as separator.

Comment: actually we already updated the .yml with your example , but we not get any exception when args not meet the limits

Comment: Without a concrete example, there is not much I can tell you